# Drop down menu triggering on iPad landscape mode

Tags: ios, css, ipad, drop-down-menu, touch

We have a simple CSS based (no JS) drop down menu on our website that works perfectly in every way except one. On the iPad in landscape mode, if you click a link below the menu (for example the breadcrumbs) touching the link triggers the fly-out which then causes you to trigger a link in the fly-out when you release your finger instead of the link you originally touched.

```
<li>
    <a href="http://categorypage">
    <ul class="flyout">
        <li><a href="blah...

.header li:hover .flyout {
    display: block;
}
```

The site (warning adult content) is http://www.lovehoney.co.uk

Things I have tried so far without success:

1. Changing the z-indexes of the containers.
2. Forced display none on the fly-outs of course blocks the fly-outs but you can still see the nav being triggered so I don't think it is the fly-outs at fault.
3. pointer-events: none on fly outs when closed.

Other info

1. The problem affects iPad 4 in landscape mode but not iPad 1
2. The bug is present in both Chrome and Safari
3. Portrait mode is fine.
4. Clicking above the nav doesn't trigger the problem.

Comment: For some reason it seems that removing float left from the logo fixes the problem. Unfortunately this causes a lot more woe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I fixed this by changing the viewport meta to

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1" />
```

This reduced the responsiveness a little but solved the problem.